# How do I paste clipboard items and add an underline on MacOS?

Tags: macos

I am trying to find a way where I can copy some text and then when I paste it to Notes I want the content to be underlined on paste.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to paste the text, then select it and press ⌘U to underline it. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Paco... I am familiar with this approach, but it is not what I am looking for. I am seeking a way to have it underline on paste. Any thoughts?